# Error in JNLP file while trying to embed the html file(generated by netbeans while building fxml project) with that of html page of a template

Tags: html, netbeans, javafx, web-deployment, jnlp

I created a javafx fxml project "Login" in netbeans. An html file named "Login.html" was created automatically. Along with this "Login.jnlp" file was also created.

I want to load "Login.html" into an existing html page of a web template in netbeans. I read from the given below link that in netbeans ID, we can specify the input HTML template file in the Run category of project properties.

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/packaging.htm#BABFFCEI

I did the same but now I am getting error "JNLP failed:null". I don't know what I have done wrong. Please help me.

Here is my Login.jnlp file

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0" xmlns:jfx="http://javafx.com" href="Login.jnlp">
  <information>
    <title>Login</title>
    <vendor>sachi</vendor>
    <description>null</description>
    <offline-allowed/>
  </information>
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
    <jar href="Login.jar" size="15390" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib\derby.jar" size="2767455" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib\derbyLocale_cs.jar" size="94402" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib\derbyLocale_de_DE.jar" size="106528" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib\derbyLocale_es.jar" size="100641" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib\derbyLocale_fr.jar" size="106650" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib\derbyLocale_hu.jar" size="95104" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib\derbyLocale_it.jar" size="100488" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib\derbyLocale_ja_JP.jar" size="117126" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib\derbyLocale_ko_KR.jar" size="111545" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib\derbyLocale_pl.jar" size="93083" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib\derbyLocale_pt_BR.jar" size="90338" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib\derbyLocale_ru.jar" size="120950" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib\derbyLocale_zh_CN.jar" size="103466" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib\derbyLocale_zh_TW.jar" size="105050" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib\derbyclient.jar" size="577598" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib\derbynet.jar" size="249873" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib\derbyrun.jar" size="8180" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib\derbytools.jar" size="212990" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib\jfoenix.jar" size="2219684" download="eager" />
  </resources>
<security>
  <all-permissions/>
</security>
  <applet-desc  width="800" height="600" main-class="com.javafx.main.NoJavaFXFallback"  name="Login" >
    <param name="requiredFXVersion" value="8.0+"/>
  </applet-desc>
  <jfx:javafx-desc  width="800" height="600" main-class="login.Login"  name="Login" />
  <update check="always"/>
</jnlp>
```

here is the "Login.html" file (generated by netbeans automatically). I wanted to embed this file in some html file from a website template.

```html
<html><head>
  <SCRIPT src="./web-files/dtjava.js"></SCRIPT>
<script>
    function launchApplication(jnlpfile) {
        dtjava.launch(            {
                url : 'Login.jnlp',
                jnlp_content : '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'
            },
            {
                javafx : '8.0+'
            },
            {
              
            }
        );
        return false;
    }
</script>

<script>
    function javafxEmbedlogin() {
        dtjava.embed(
            {
                id : 'login',
                url : 'Login.jnlp',
                placeholder : 'javafx-app-placeholder',
                width : '800',
                height : '600',
                jnlp_content : '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'
            },
            {
                javafx : '8.0+'
            },
            {}
        );
    }
    <!-- Embed FX application into web page once page is loaded -->
    dtjava.addOnloadCallback(javafxEmbedlogin);
</script>

</head><body>
<h2>Test page for <b>Login</b></h2>
  <b>Webstart:</b> <a href='Login.jnlp' onclick="return launchApplication('Login.jnlp');">click to launch this app as webstart</a><br><hr><br>

  <!-- Applet will be inserted here -->
  <div id='javafx-app-placeholder'></div>
</body></html>
```

here is the output log in netbeans

```html
ant -f C:\\Users\\sachi\\OneDrive\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Login jfxbe-run
init:
deps-clean:
Updating property file: C:\Users\sachi\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Login\build\built-clean.properties
Deleting directory C:\Users\sachi\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Login\build
clean:
init:
deps-jar:
Created dir: C:\Users\sachi\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Login\build
Updating property file: C:\Users\sachi\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Login\build\built-jar.properties
Created dir: C:\Users\sachi\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Login\build\classes
Created dir: C:\Users\sachi\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Login\build\empty
Created dir: C:\Users\sachi\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Login\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
Compiling 4 source files to C:\Users\sachi\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Login\build\classes
Copying 10 files to C:\Users\sachi\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Login\build\classes
Copied 1 empty directory to 1 empty directory under C:\Users\sachi\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Login\build\classes
compile:
Created dir: C:\Users\sachi\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Login\dist
Copying 19 files to C:\Users\sachi\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Login\dist\lib
Copied 1 empty directory to 1 empty directory under C:\Users\sachi\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Login\dist\lib
Detected JavaFX Ant API version 1.3
Going to create default keystore in C:\Users\sachi\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Login\build\nb-jfx.jks
Generating Key for nb-jfx
Launching <fx:jar> task from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\..\lib\ant-javafx.jar
Warning: From JDK7u25 the Codebase manifest attribute should be used to restrict JAR repurposing.
         Please set manifest.custom.codebase property to override the current default non-secure value '*'.
Launching <fx:signjar> task from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\..\lib\ant-javafx.jar
Signing (BLOB) C:\Users\sachi\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Login\dist\Login.jar
Signing (BLOB) C:\Users\sachi\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Login\dist\lib\derby.jar
Signing (BLOB) C:\Users\sachi\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Login\dist\lib\derbyLocale_cs.jar
Signing (BLOB) C:\Users\sachi\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Login\dist\lib\derbyLocale_de_DE.jar
Signing (BLOB) C:\Users\sachi\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Login\dist\lib\derbyLocale_es.jar
Signing (BLOB) C:\Users\sachi\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Login\dist\lib\derbyLocale_fr.jar
Signing (BLOB) C:\Users\sachi\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Login\dist\lib\derbyLocale_hu.jar
Signing (BLOB) C:\Users\sachi\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Login\dist\lib\derbyLocale_it.jar
Signing (BLOB) C:\Users\sachi\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Login\dist\lib\derbyLocale_ja_JP.jar
Signing (BLOB) C:\Users\sachi\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Login\dist\lib\derbyLocale_ko_KR.jar
Signing (BLOB) C:\Users\sachi\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Login\dist\lib\derbyLocale_pl.jar
Signing (BLOB) C:\Users\sachi\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Login\dist\lib\derbyLocale_pt_BR.jar
Signing (BLOB) C:\Users\sachi\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Login\dist\lib\derbyLocale_ru.jar
Signing (BLOB) C:\Users\sachi\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Login\dist\lib\derbyLocale_zh_CN.jar
Signing (BLOB) C:\Users\sachi\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Login\dist\lib\derbyLocale_zh_TW.jar
Signing (BLOB) C:\Users\sachi\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Login\dist\lib\derbyclient.jar
Signing (BLOB) C:\Users\sachi\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Login\dist\lib\derbynet.jar
Signing (BLOB) C:\Users\sachi\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Login\dist\lib\derbyrun.jar
Signing (BLOB) C:\Users\sachi\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Login\dist\lib\derbytools.jar
Signing (BLOB) C:\Users\sachi\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Login\dist\lib\jfoenix.jar
Launching <fx:deploy> task from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\..\lib\ant-javafx.jar
No base JDK. Package will use system JRE.
JNLP failed : null
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
 at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:570)
 at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:190)
 at com.oracle.tools.packager.jnlp.JNLPBundler.readTextFile(JNLPBundler.java:391)
 at com.oracle.tools.packager.jnlp.JNLPBundler.execute(JNLPBundler.java:547)
 at com.sun.javafx.tools.packager.PackagerLib.generateNativeBundles(PackagerLib.java:352)
 at com.sun.javafx.tools.packager.PackagerLib.generateDeploymentPackages(PackagerLib.java:318)
 at com.sun.javafx.tools.ant.DeployFXTask.execute(DeployFXTask.java:286)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$155$\^eval\_.:program(<eval>:405)
 at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunctionData.invoke(ScriptFunctionData.java:640)
 at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction.invoke(ScriptFunction.java:228)
 at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime.apply(ScriptRuntime.java:393)
 at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:446)
 at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:403)
 at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:399)
 at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.eval(NashornScriptEngine.java:155)
 at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:264)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor238.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.util.ReflectUtil.invoke(ReflectUtil.java:108)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.util.ReflectWrapper.invoke(ReflectWrapper.java:81)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.util.optional.JavaxScriptRunner.evaluateScript(JavaxScriptRunner.java:103)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.util.optional.JavaxScriptRunner.executeScript(JavaxScriptRunner.java:67)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.Script.execute(Script.java:52)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor162.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor162.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:396)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor162.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:441)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor162.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:286)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:555)
 at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
C:\Users\sachi\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Login\nbproject\jfx-impl.xml:1465: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\sachi\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Login\nbproject\jfx-impl.xml:3017: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\sachi\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Login\nbproject\jfx-impl.xml:2055: Error: Bundler "WebStart JNLP Bundler" (jnlp) failed to produce a bundle.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 5 seconds)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself.
There was nothing wrong with jnlp file.
I have answered one of my own asked question which had the same issue.
[how to insert html code generated in javafx fxml project in an existing web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41271288/how-to-insert-html-code-generated-in-javafx-fxml-project-in-an-existing-web-page)